# Devise current_user not persistent on idle page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently working on a system with custom devise registration controller. The odd thing that is happening is when the page is not used for a while, the `current_user` variable gets `nil` value. I've placed logging on different parts of the system and found out that at the following method, the resource is not set:

```
# Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
def authenticate_scope!
  send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", force: true)
  self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
end
```

When I checked the session, it suddenly changes value.

```
Sign-in action:
{"session_id"=>"5b714b8718d1c83d3a19f83355f98c69", "user_return_to"=>"/users/edit", "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007ff2426a9208 @used=#<Set: {:notice}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:notice=>"Signed in successfully."}, @now=nil>, "warden.user.user.key"=>[[46], "$2a$10$9x4tg9SvShVBgGPejhbliu"], "_csrf_token"=>"gOqNojt6SdyVs69kVZcYYBrrAWIB8U07MqWs7rfqbO8="}

No idle time:
{"session_id"=>"5b714b8718d1c83d3a19f83355f98c69", "user_return_to"=>"/users/edit", "warden.user.user.key"=>[[46], "$2a$10$9x4tg9SvShVBgGPejhbliu"], "_csrf_token"=>"gOqNojt6SdyVs69kVZcYYBrrAWIB8U07MqWs7rfqbO8="}

With idle time: 
{"session_id"=>"5b714b8718d1c83d3a19f83355f98c69", "user_return_to"=>"/users/edit", "_csrf_token"=>"gOqNojt6SdyVs69kVZcYYBrrAWIB8U07MqWs7rfqbO8=", "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x000000066e9078 @used=#<Set: {:alert}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:alert=>"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}, @now=nil>}
```

How can I trace the session changes? Or is there a way to check when it changes?

I just checked the gemfile and it includes devise-async. Does this have an impact?

The gems are: `gem 'rails', '3.2.17', gem 'devise', '3.2.3', gem 'devise-async', '0.9.0'`

I'm not sure how to trace this further after getting stuck at `send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)`. I placed the bundles inside the project (./bundle), placed loggers inside the devise and it always halts in this code. How can I debug the `send` method?

Comment: Is :timeoutable enabled for devise?

Comment: I checked the user model and timeoutable is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the things you ask when you're stuck... I feel stupid now after solving this. I even forgot to mention that the system is multitenant.

So for those who have the same problem, check tenant: `Apartment::Tenant.current`. Chances are, it reverts to `public`. As to why it does that, I don't have an idea.